# RQT: setNativeLocks failed

Tags: ros-kinetic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using ROS Kinetic in Ubuntu 16.04

I find that if I use any of the rqt_* commands such as rqt_graph, the terminal hangs and I get a continuous error as under

```
setNativeLocks failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
setNativeLocks failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
setNativeLocks failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
setNativeLocks failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

If I kill the process, then I get the below error

```
sigint_handler()
MainWindow.closeEvent()
Killed
```

I checked the Qt bindings and it looks like I am using PyQt5

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import python_qt_binding
>>> print(python_qt_binding.QT_BINDING)
pyqt
>>> from python_qt_binding.QtWidgets import QWidget
>>> print(python_qt_binding.QT_BINDING_VERSION)
5.5.1
```

Not sure how to debug this issue. Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314398/rqt:-setnativelocks-failed/) by [siddadd](https://answers.ros.org/users/39782/siddadd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From some Googling this seems like an issue with Qt (5). Some results seem to indicate it has to do with file locking. Are you running this in a VM, have a home dir mounted over NFS, a file with `/dev` in its name in `/tmp` or some other strange setup?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [siddadd](https://answers.ros.org/users/39782/siddadd/) on 2019-02-04**:
Thanks for the comment @gvdhoorn. It was my home dir mounted over NFS that was causing the issue. I unmounted it and the locks have disappeared.